# Cant sign into Ubuntu - 'unlock disk sda3_crypt' message

Tags: 16.04

I've had Ubuntu 16.04 on my new PC for 2 weeks now but today I went to reset it and now I can't log in. A black box on the top left pops up and I only type in there. Really would appreciate and help.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by reset?

Comment: Basically restart the pc.

Comment: It seems you have been infected by some kind of ransomware. Hope you have backup of your data because there is a little chance to get your data back without payment. Check [here](https://www.nomoreransom.org/).

Comment: I was able to gain access through recovery mode. The issue though is whenever I restart the system I can't go through like I would always anymore.

Comment: Check your documents, they are first targets. See if you can open them.

Comment: This totally looks like someone hijacked your system, yes.

Comment: I can access all my files like I usually would.

Comment: If they are not encrypted then backup them ASAP. The message on top left is not part of Ubuntu screen for sure. Check your system by an Anti-Virus.

Comment: Alright I'm gonna back up all the files and then wipe the ssd

Comment: Did you install with the LVM / full disk encryption option? it looks somewhat similar to this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/1386005)

Comment: Yes!!! That was exactly it. I went ahead and created a back up, wiped all data off my ssd and restored all files but removed the sda3_crypt so it won't happen again. Though it doesn't load as it did before with similar faults on the top left I can still load into my pc. Wish I was able to keep the extra security but seems ima have to look more into it so it doesn't happen again.Thanks much for this.